# Changing language in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, function, kendo-ui

I use Kendo UI to create grids. I use opcion  data-filterable to filter data.
I would like to change language from English to Polish.
How should I do it?

[image]

Below, you can find my script . I would like to exchange " Is equal to " on polish equivalent.

```js
  var viewModel;
        viewModel = kendo.observable({
            isVisible: true,
            products: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ProductID",
                        fields: {
                            login: {type: "string"},
                            naz_druk: {type: "string"},
                            naz_wys: {type: "string"},
                            zabl: {type: "string"},
                            arch: {type: "string"},
                            ost_log: {type: "date"},
                            il_log: {type: "number"},
                            gen_zap: {type: "number"},
                            il_zap: {type: "number"}
                        }
                    }
                },
                    batch: true,
                    data: [{
                        "login": "AGCDE",
                        "naz_druk": "Jan Kowalski",
                        "naz_wys": "Jan Kowalski",
                        "zabl": "TAK",
                        "arch": "NIE",
                        "ost_log": "12/12/2016",
                        "il_log": "5",
                        "gen_zap": "5",
                        "il_zap": "5"
                    },
                        {
                            "login": "bbbGCDE",
                            "naz_druk": "Jan Nowak",
                            "naz_wys": "Jan Nowak",
                            "zabl": "NIE",
                            "arch": "NIE",
                            "ost_log": "12/06/2016",
                            "il_log": "2",
                            "gen_zap": "2",
                            "il_zap": "2"
                        }]
                })
        });
        kendo.bind($("#oknoGlowne"), viewModel);
```

```html
meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8" />
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="format_cs.css">-->

        <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/mvvm">
        <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.uniform.min.css" />

        <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/shared/styles/examples-offline.css">
        <script src="../content/shared/js/console.js"></script>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div>
    <!-- Container glówne okno-->
    <div id="oknoGlowne"
         data-role="window"
         data-title="Lista użytkowników"
         data-bind="visible: isVisible"
         data-width="800"
         data-height="400"
         style="padding:0; border: none;"
         data-actions="[
                 'Pin',
                 'Minimize',
                 'Maximize',
                 'Close',
                 ]"
    >

        <div data-role="splitter"
             data-orientation="vertical"
             data-panes="[{
             collapsible: false,
             resizable: false,
             size: '30px'
             },{
             collapsible: false,
             resizable: true
             }]"
             style="height: 100%; border: none;">
            <!-- Główny div-->
            <div>
                <!-- Menu główne-->
                <div class="menuGlowne"
                     data-role="menu"
                     data-resizable="true"
                     data-bind="events: { select: onMenuSelect }"
                     style="width: 100%; border: none;background-color: lightgray; ">
                    <li><input class="search"
                               style="width:150px;"
                               data-spinners="false"
                               placeholder="Rola"></li>
                    <li><input class="search"
                               style="width:150px;"
                               data-spinners="false"
                               placeholder="Loginid"></li>
                    <li data-menu-id="dodajUzytkownika"
                        data-title="Dodaj użytkownika"
                        data-role="tooltip"
                        data-auto-hide="true"
                        data-position="top">
                        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span></li>
                    <li data-menu-id="edycjauzytkownika"
                        data-title="Edytuj/uzupełnij dane użytkownika"
                        data-role="tooltip"
                        data-auto-hide="true"
                        data-position="top">
                        <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span></li>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div data-role="grid"
                         data-editable="false"
                         data-sortable="true"
                         data-pageable='{
                             "previousNext": true,
                             "numeric": true,
                             "pageSizes": true,
                             "info": true
                             }'

                         data-resizable="true"
                         data-columns="[
                             { 'field': 'login', 'width': 50, 'title' : 'Login'},
                             { 'field': 'naz_druk','width': 50, 'title' : 'Nazwa drukowana' },
                             { 'field': 'naz_wys','width': 50, 'title' : 'Nazwa wyświetlana' },
                             { 'field': 'zabl','width': 20, 'title' : 'Zablokowany' },
                             { 'field': 'arch','width': 20, 'title' : 'Zarchiwizowany' },
                             { 'field': 'ost_log','width': 50, 'title' : 'Ostatnie logowanie','format': '{0:MM/dd/yyyy}' },
                             { 'field': 'il_log','width': 20, 'title' : 'Ilość logowań' },
                             { 'field': 'gen_zap','width': 20, 'title' : 'Wygenerowane zapytania' },
                             { 'field': 'il_zap', 'width': 20,'title' : 'Ilość zapytań' },
                             ]"
                         data-bind="source: products,
                            visible: isVisible,
                            events: {
                            save: onSave
                            }"

                         data-filterable="[
                         { field: 'login', operator: 'startswith' },
                         { field: 'naz_druk', operator: 'startswith' },
                         { field: 'naz_wys', operator: 'startswith' },
                         { field: 'zabl', operator: 'startswith' },
                         { field: 'arch', operator: 'startswith' },
                         { field: 'ost_log', operator: 'startswith' },
                         { field: 'il_log', operator: 'startswith' },
                         { field: 'gen_zap', operator: 'startswith' },
                         { field: 'il_zap', extra: 'false', operator: 'number' },

                         ]"

                         style="height: 100%; border: none;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to search here?

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/localization/overview

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can do kendo.culture("en-US") to change it to English (change value for Polish iso code), but you also need to include the culture js file for the languages you support.  If you want a hybrid (mainly english with Polish on the menu), you will have to manually set those messages yourself.  You can do so with calls to override the messages directly like this:

```
kendo.ui.FilterCell.prototype.options.operators.string.eq = "Some Value"
```